# How to specify the spreadsheet tab name of a Google form destination using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm working with Google Script Editor and I've created a form using based on a Google Sheet.  I've specified helptext for certain questions on the form based on the current cell selected from my sheet.  Then I've set the destination for my form results into a different Google sheet.  I want to specify the name of the tab based on that current cell from the current sheet.  Is that possible?  Here is what I have right now:

```
var DestinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('URL here');
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, DestinationSheet.getId(););
```

But how do I specify the TAB name, as right now it just gives it a generic name with a new number each time, i.e., "Form Responses 5".

I thought I could include this somehow:
`DestinationSheet.insertSheet("currentcell");`
But that just inserts yet another sheet named "currentcell".

Answer (score 4):

> But how do I specify the TAB name, as right now it just gives it a generic name with a new number each time, i.e., "Form Responses 5".

It's currently not possible to set the sheet name. But you can rename the `"Form Responses 5"` sheet.

#### Snippet:

```
const DestinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('URL here');
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, DestinationSheet.getId());
  const formUrl = form.getEditUrl();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  DestinationSheet
    .getSheets()
    .forEach(function(sheet){
       const sheetUrl = sheet.getFormUrl()
       //TODO Check format of both urls
       console.log({sheetUrl, formUrl})
       if (sheetUrl  === formUrl) 
        sheet.setName(DestinationSheet.getCurrentCell().getValue());//Function should be called from menu/button
    })
```

#### References:

- [Sheet#getFormUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getFormUrl())
- [Form#getEditUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getEditUrl())

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me.  The form is still named "Form Responses XX".  XX being a random number.

Comment: @Amy Show values of `sheetUrl` and `formUrl`

Comment: It doesn't work because .getSheets() does not contain the new sheet during that execution.

It does list the sheet the next time the script is executed, but that's not helpful.

I'm guessing you need to wait after .setDestination(...) for the new sheet to be created. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: @JamesTalmage Add     `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before `.getSheets()` line

Comment: This isn't working for me, either, and I don't see how it's supposed to. sheetUrl and formUrl return the URLs to edit and view the forms. They have nothing to do with the Form Responses Tab created in the Destination Sheet, and as far as I can see, this script snippet does not interface with that Tab in any way. OP is asking how specify the Tab name in the same step as setDestination. Even if it can't be done in the same step, it should be doable if we can get either the name or ID of the newly created Tab. I don't see that the question has been answered.

Comment: I ended up doing this - maybe a bit lazy but it seems like setting a destination form always adds the new sheet to the beginning. SpreadsheetApp.flush() is key!! Thank you @TheMaster

`form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, spreadsheet.getId());

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    let destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

    destinationSheet.setName(desiredName);`

Comment: @AtiqZabinski `sheet.getFormUrl()` does get the url from the destination sheet, where `sheet` comes from the destination sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Now form urls are suffixed with `/edit` and `/viewport`, which you must remove to properly compare. I end up with this solution:

```
function connectCurrentSpreadsheet(form, sheetName) {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, spreadsheet.getId());

  // rename spreadsheet
  const formUrl = form.getEditUrl().replace('/edit', '');
  spreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    const destFormUrl = sheet.getFormUrl().replace('/viewform', '');
    if(destFormUrl === formUrl) {
      sheet.setName(sheetName);
    }
  });
}
```